# Is it possible to control 3 DC motors (12V, 5A) with a single driver (BTS7960-43A) if the motors should rotate 1 at a time?

Tags: arduino, motor, dc-motor, mosfet-driver

I have to use 3 DC motors in a project, each of them are 12V-5A, controlled by Arduino. At any given point, only one motor will be operating. So I want to avoid 3 separate drivers for 3 motors. Instead, is it possible to use single driver for 3 motors (using BTS7960 - 43A driver)? If yes, how can I keep other 2 motors off when one of them is running?

Similar setup like in pic

[image: BTS7960]

Comment: You could potentially use relays for motor selection, stress on the relays will be much lower if your software only ever switches them when the electronic control is fully off.  Often it's cleaner to just use a distinct driver for each motor, but you might be in the territory where the driver is expensive enough that relays to multiplex could be barely worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But for 3 motors I need 3 to 6 relays  in total. Size becomes big. Are there any tiny solid state relay package with high current capability (10-15A) ?

Comment: By the time you get a solid state relay that works in both polarities with low loss you should perhaps just give each motor its own H-bridge.